# Entity Framework Core updating database withing project

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have made a blazor project that is hooked up to a database that pulls information via a form. I have also gone ahead and added a migration for this DB. Now our production database has new tables being made every 90 days. My question is for EF Core is there something I can write in the code that would update my solution with the newest Db changes and runs once a day? I have read up on EF Core scripts but could not find any concrete examples. Any advice would be grealy appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is a Blazor Server app, in your `Program.cs` you can migrate your database every time the application starts (if there are new migrations) by doing something like this:

```
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
var context = services.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();
await context.Database.Migrate(); // or MigrateAsync();
host.Run();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot!